# What to chant before taking and consuming prasad?

Tags: mantras, shloka, prasad

What to chant before taking and consuming prasad from anyone for any god ... is there a common mantra or thank you shloka ?

Comment: when eating food daily, there is a set of mantras and actions using water for purifying the food and preparing the stomach, called parisechana. For bhagavad prasad, like fruits/nuts/sweets, since it is already anointed by priests and offered to bhagavan, it is consumed as is. I'm not aware of a special mantra just for prasad. Before eating the first morsel though, it is customary to chant 'Govinda'.

Answer (score 5):

As far as I'm aware of there is no such Mantra/Sloka which should be chanted while consuming Prasada. But there is a Sloka which is usually chanted while consuming Tirtha (or holy water which has touched the deity). It is also chanted by the priests in many temples while distributing Tirtha water to devotees.

What the devotees do is accept the Tirtha in their right palm, chant the Sloka and then sip the Tirtha. This is done with the belief that by consuming this holy water one can avoid untimely death, diseases etc.

Quoting from [Hindupedia.com](http://www.hindupedia.com/en/Slokas_for_solving_various_problems), the following is the Sloka:

> 45.To take the sacred water after anointing God
>
> 1.Akala mruthyu haranam , sarva vyadhi nivaranam,
>   SAmastha papa kshaya karam , Shiva(Vishnu) padodakam ||
>
> The water washing the feet of Lord Shiva(vishnu)  Would avoid
>   accidental early deaths , Would cure all diseases,  And would also
>   destroy all the sins committed.

Also, this Sloka is a general one. One can replace Shiva/Vishnu in it with the deity of which the Tirtha is being consumed.

Also, note that between Tirtha of God and his Prasada there isn't any difference. Both have equal grace and touch of God. So, if one wants to modify the Sloka to Prasada taking scenario, one can simply replace the word "Padodakam" in the Sloka with "Prasadam". Or else one can simply chant the same Sloka as it is.

Comment: fyi, Tirtha is not given in shiva sannidhi. Other than vibhuthi, no prasad. In fact, there is a saying 'shiva sotthu kula nasam' - shiva's wealth family ruin (meaning if you take something from temple as yours, it leads to ruin), so orthodox iyer brahmins would physically shake off their clothes when leaving temple, so as to not even take home dust.

Comment: @ram That's true. They go to Chandeeshwara sannidhi before leaving the temple and just show their hands (coconuts these days) to show that they are taking nothing which is related to Shiva to their home. Otherwise, Chandeeshwara would be angry.

Comment: That must be a regional view. Such mindset isn't prevailing anywhere in Aryavarta. @ram

Comment: @Rickross, yes, I agree. it must be a regional view for Aryavarta to not follow it.